# Rails scoped form not assigning belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, belongs-to

I have two models in Rails 3 - a User model and a Profile model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

They are scoped in my routes.rb file, as such:

```
resources :users do
  resources :profiles
end
```

So now, my form to create a profile reads like this (Using SimpleForm):

```
<%= simple_form_for([@user, @profile]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
    ...(Other Inputs)
<% end %>
```

However, the user ID doesn't seem to be automatically sent to the profile model as I had assumed.  Do I have to set that manually through the controller?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Have the records for profiles in database a field `user_id` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by making sure that the relationship between User and Profile is indeed working correctly. You've actually put "has_one :user" in your User model, when I think you mean:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

In order to send the user ID with the form, the form should be on a page with a URL of something like "localhost:3000/users/5/profiles/new" which you can link to with the helper "new_user_profile_path(5)", for a user with ID 5.

When you submit the form, it will hit the create action in your ProfilesController. The following should result in the creation of the profile:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @profile = @user.build_profile(params[:profile])
  @profile.save!
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the line:

`@profile = @user.build_profile(params[:profile])`

Instead, I had just been using:

`@profile = Profile.new(params[:profile])`

Answer (score 0):

add :method => :post to your form since ur html request is GET which should be POST

```
simple_form_for([@user, @profile], :method => :post) do |f| %>
```